# In Delphi, I send AnsiString Data to C++ DLL Function, but input value was lost. Why happened this situation?

Tags: c++, delphi, memory, dll, c-strings

I got to know a little bit more detailed issues. So, I changed Question.
Thanks to people who previous question about the answered.

Now, It is a detailed question.
In delphi, I send data of AnsiString type to C++ Function in DLL

**In Delphi07**

```
TFunctionA = function (aHandle: FunctionAHANDLE ; input: AnsiString): AnsiString; cdecl;
....
FunctionA('Test string value');
```

**In C++ DLL**

```
    char * FunctionA(char *input){
       ....
    return pReturn;
    };
```

In situation, I confirmed data(char *input) using Visual Studio 15 Debug, the data was lost(AnsiString)

But In Delphi, TFunctionA's Return type change AnsiString to AnsiChar, 
and then data(char *input) is transmitted("Test string value").

```
 TFunctionA = function (aHandle: FunctionAHANDLE ; input: AnsiString): AnsiChar; cdecl;
```

I don't know this situation because, I have never worked with Delphi.

Comment: There is a bug in the code. Not particularly helpful, but the best anyone can probably do for you without a [mcve] or a crystal ball.

Comment: What is `CString`? A C++ class containing a string? If so, Delphi won't be able to use it. What is that "other function" and what does it do? Like @user4581301 says, show a [mcve]. It is unclear what is happening from your rather vague description.

Comment: Defect in your code. Either debug it yourself or show MCVE.

Comment: Oddly enough @RudyVelthuis, your blog came up on the first page of google results (Delphi CString) when I checked to make sure CString hadn't been snuck into Delphi since the last time I'd worked with it.

Comment: This sounds like when "another function execute in Delphi" it is corrupting memory and the `CString` variable just *happens* to be the victim. Its allocated memory block holding the character data is not being corrupted, but its internal pointer to the memory block is getting overwritten.

Comment: @user4581301: I guess my blog talks about "C strings" (`char *` strings), not about `CString`, but it is indeed odd that my blog came up so early. <g>

Comment: Your code fragments don't fit together for me, but FWIW: a `char*` in C++ is a `PAnsiChar` in Delphi, *not* an `AnsiString`!

Comment: You really completely rewrote your question. AnsiString is a Delphi specific type, and its lifetime is managed by the runtime. Do not pass non-POD types to DLLs or expose them from DLLs. Only use POD (Plain Old Data) types, nothing else. `AnsiString` is not a POD type. `char *` is. Its Delphi equivalent is `PAnsiChar`. Read this: http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pchars.html .

Comment: More important, when returning a character string over the DLL boundary, either 1) the callee allocates and fills the memory and then the caller frees it when done using it, or 2) the caller allocates the memory and pass it to the callee to fill in. In the case of #1, the caller can free the memory directly *only if* both caller and callee share a common memory manager, otherwise the caller has to pass the string back to the callee to free it using the same memory manager that allocated it. Examples of these techniques are widely available if you search around.

Comment: Thanks to everybody! I eventually know that `char *` is `PAnisiChar` in delphi.  Also,  Your are to broaden my knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delphi's `AnsiString` is similar but definitely not the same thing as C's `char *`. Assuming your C function is:

```
char * FunctionA(char *input){
   ....
return pReturn;
};
```

Then your Delphi declaration should look like this:

```
function FunctionA(Input: PAnsiString): PAnsiString; cdecl;
```

And you would use it in this fashion:

```
var
  SomeInput, SomeOutput: AnsiString;
begin
  SomeInput := 'foobar';
  SomeOutput := AnsiString(FunctionA(PAnsiChar(SomeInput)));
  Writeln(SomeOutput);
end;
```

Here you first "convert" (not really, but close enough) `AnsiString` SomeInput to `PAnsiChar`, which is a zero-terminated string exactly equal to C's `char *`. You pass that to your C function, then convert (really) the `char *` result (same thing as Delphi's `PAnsiChar`) to Delphi's `AnsiString`.

Or, if you want to explain it in C/C++ terms, you have a C++ `string` which you can "convert" to `char *` using `string::c_str()`, and then you create a new `string` based on a `char *` thanks to a `string(char *)` constructor.